# Apéndices (Appendix spanish accent)

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, accents, spanish

Dear friends: there is a problem with appendix and ápendice.

I have a `scrbook` document and I use appendix package,

```
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}
```

because I like the word "Apéndice" in the `toc`

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

However, when I compile with `latex` there is an error in `file.toc` (maybe in `file.aux` before). The reason is that in the `file.aux` there is a line like this:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{Ap\IeC {\'e}ndice \numberline {A}Sobre el \LaTeX  }{27}{ApÈndice.1.Alph1}}
```

and in the second compilation the character "È" produces and error. If I compile with `lualatex` I have not any error.

I have tried to modify `\indexname`, `\@chapapp` but I can not find any solution.

---

Yes, that is a solution. I am going to clarify the problem with a MWE. In my opinion the problem is motivated by UTF-8 codify and `inputenc` package, as it is possible to see with this code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,10pt, twoside]{scrbook}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{tgheros}    % (Una versión libre de Helvetica)
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhv} %qhv

%:Fuente para todo lo demás (Una versión libre de Times)
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qtm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\normalfont

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %para LaTex 

%:Paquetes relacionados con el idioma y codificación
\usepackage[english, spanish, es-nosectiondot, es-noindentfirst, es-nolists, activeacute]{babel} 
\spanishdecimal{.}

%:Para poner las referencias y los nombres de figuras y tablas en castellano
\addto\captionsspanish
{%
\def\figurename{Figura}%
\def\tablename{Tabla}%
\def\listfigurename{Índice de Figuras}
\def\listtablename{Índice de Tablas}
\def\contentsname{Índice}%
\def\chaptername{Capítulo}
\def\Agradecimientos{Agradecimientos}
\def\Prefacename{Prefacio}%
\def\refname{Referencias}%
\def\abstractname{Resumen}%
\def\bibname{{Bibliografía}}
\def\appendixname{Apéndice}
\def\miapendice{\appendixname}
\def\glossaryname{Glosario}%
\def\indexname{{Índice Alfabético}}
}

%:Para definir APÉNDICES
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

%:Empieza el contenido del libro
\mainmatter

\chapter{Primer capítulo}
\section{Primera sección, primer capítulo}

\chapter{Segundo capítulo}
\section{Primera sección, segundo capítulo}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Primer apéndice}
\section{Primera sección, primer apéndice}

\chapter{Segundo apéndice}
\section{Primera sección, segundo apéndice}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

If you compile, you obtain this error message:

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:énd not set up for use with La- TeXSee the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Your command was ignored.Type I   to replace it with another command,or  to continue without it.ice.alph1.Alph11ice.alph1.Alph20P

But the solution proposed it is perfect. Thank you

Comment: Hi Javier, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your code using the `{}` and backticks- it just makes it a bit easier to distinguish code from text. It would be best if you could post a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to help those who might be able to work on your problem. Welcome to the group!

Comment: Please edit your question and add a minimal, yet *complete*, version of your document allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Javier: I could answer just because this reminded me about another question. Please, always try to present a minimal complete example; I add one to my answer so you can adjust it if something doesn't work as advertised.

Answer (score 14):

This seems very similar to [How to make appendix and hyperref packages work together with cyrillic (non ASCII) characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41649/how-to-make-appendix-and-hyperref-packages-work-together-with-cyrillic-non-asci) and indeed a part of that answer should make your day.

Add the following after loading `appendix` (it's needed only when `hyperref` is used)

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\appto{\appendices}{\def\Hy@chapapp{Appendix}}
\makeatother
```

For some reasons, `hyperref` defines `\Hy@chapapp` as `\appendixname`, which in turn becomes (with Spanish `babel` and `appendix`) `\spanishappendixname` that again becomes `Ap\'{e}ndice`. However, it seems that `\Hy@chapapp` is used only for building the anchor name for hyperlinks, so it should be immaterial what string is used, as long as it is unique. Since the expansion of `\Hy@chapapp` is subject to complete expansion, it's better for it to be composed by characters only.

Here's a minimal document

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % we load it for the workaround
\usepackage{hyperref}

% workaround
\makeatletter
\appto{\appendices}{\def\Hy@chapapp{Appendix}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Sobre el \LaTeX}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is the solution to my problem too (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472555/91816).