# What may cause bookmark accented letters not working on a specific computer?

Tags: hyperref, luatex, bookmarks, appendix

I'm using package `hyperref` to write a book in Portuguese. Appendices should appear in TOC as in `Apêndice A Title of the appendix`.

When I compile it with LuaLatex on a computer with Ubuntu 16.04, I get this error message:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\char 
l.2 ....a.A}{Ap\352ndice T\355tulo de ap\352ndice}{}
```

The file `main.out` looks like this:

```
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{chapter.1}{Blabla}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{Ap\char "00EA\relax ndice.a.A}{Ap\352ndice T\355tulo de ap\352ndice}{}% 2
```

But, when I compile the same project with LuaLatex on a computer with Ubuntu 18.10, I get no error message and the file `main.out` looks like this:

```
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{chapter.1}{Blabla}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{Apêndice.a.A}{Ap\352ndice T\355tulo de ap\352ndice}{}% 2
```

What can possible be wrong with LuaLatex on my Ubuntu 16.04?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Apêndice}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[notlof,notlot,nottoc]{tocbibind}

\title{TÍTULO DO LIVRO}
\author{Nome do Autor}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage 

\mainmatter

\chapter{Blabla}

Blablabla.

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Título de apêndice}

Texto.
\newpage
Mais texto.
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use luainputenc. (I don't know if it is the source of your problem, I didn't try your MWE is far away from a minimal example.)

Comment: In titles, try to do not add explicit accented chars, instead try things like `\'a` etc.

Comment: @manooooh With LuaLaTeX that really should not be necessary. And I have never had issues with non-ASCII chars in pdfLaTeX either in those positions.

Comment: Sorry, I reduced the example further. Indeed, the problem doesn't appear when I exclude the line `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}`. But I think I included that line because I needed it in my document for some purpose. Why shouldn't I use `luainputenc`?

Comment: @manooooh I had already tried that. I had replaced `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Apêndice}` with `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Ap\^endice}`, but the error message didn't change.

Comment: You would only need `luainputenc` [if you had to combine legacy encodings and Unicode in the same document, using LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470976/are-there-cases-where-fontenc-luatex-or-xetex-cause-problems/470980#470980). If at all possible, I would advise you to instead remove any legacy font packages, and use Unicode throughout.

Comment: The problem manifested again in another computer, even without luainputenc... Not for the MWE, but for my original document.

Comment: I found what's causing the problem. It seems I can't use Babel, Hyperref, Lualatex and Bibtex together. If I add `\usepackage[greek,portuguese]{babel}` to the MWE, `lualatex` doesn't work after the `bibtex` command. The same error described in my question appears.

Comment: Just found the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58883/91816.

Comment: @Davislor I remembered today: I use luainputenc for accent letters to appear correctly in bookmarks.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro That probably is not the best approach: the `hyperref` manual says that bookmarks must be in Unicode anyway.  Your source files for LuaTeX should always be UTF-8, and you should give `hyperref` the `unicode=true` option.  The only time you’d need `luainputenc` is if you’re trying to mix Unicode with legacy 7- and 8-bit fonts, but in the real world there’s no reason to ever do that.  If you’re writing your book in LuaTeX, you can just consistently use Unicode.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro There are a handful of special cases where you might be forced to use a legacy font in the same document as Unicode.  If you’re writing a new book, though, and you’re handling details like the bookmarks yourself, and something you do needs `luainputenc`, you should stop doing it.