# Tex does not compile when jointly using longtable, appendix, hyperref, and babel (spanish). Error: "! Argument of \@let@token has an extra }"

Tags: hyperref, longtable, babel

I have a problem with `hyperref`, `longtable`, `appendix` and `babel` (`spanish`) all together. TeX does not compile, with the following error:

```
! Argument of \@let@token has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.111 1
       64700 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
?
```

An example code to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
   Chapter text
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Longtable example}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Feasible triples for
 highly variable Grid, MLMMH.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple    chosen}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ \hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
0 & (1, 11, 13725) & (1, 12, 10980), (1, 13, 8235), (2, 2, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
2745 & (1, 12, 10980) & (1, 13, 8235), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
5490 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
8235 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
10980 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
13725 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
16470 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
19215 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
21960 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
24705 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
27450 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
30195 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
32940 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
35685 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
38430 & (1, 13, 10980) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
41175 & (1, 12, 13725) & (1, 13, 10980), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
43920 & (1, 13, 10980) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
46665 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
49410 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
52155 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
54900 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
57645 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
60390 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
63135 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
65880 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
68625 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
71370 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
74115 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
76860 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
79605 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
82350 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
85095 & (1, 12, 13725) & (1, 13, 10980), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
87840 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
90585 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
93330 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
96075 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
98820 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
101565 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
104310 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
107055 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
109800 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
112545 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
115290 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
118035 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
120780 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
123525 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
126270 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
129015 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
131760 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
134505 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
137250 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
139995 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
142740 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
145485 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
148230 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
150975 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
153720 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
156465 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
159210 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
161955 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
164700 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{appendices}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

1. Removing `hyperref` solves the problem (but also removes hyperlinks, of course).
2. Using `\chapter*{Longtable example}` instead of `\chapter{Longtable example}` also compiles with no errors.
3. Changing `babel` to `english` also works.
4. The most curious thing: it was working before I updated my machine! Now, I installed latest version, i.e MiKTeX 2.9 (previously, I had v2.8) and updated all packages and the problem appeared.

I would appreciate any solution, I think this is a new error because of two things: firstly, I couldn't find anything similar in Google and secondly, it was working with previous versions of the packages and/or MiKTeX.

Extra info: OS Windows 7 x64bits, MiKTeX 2.9, all packages are updated to the latest versions. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the `.out` file and add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Like many accemted related problems things are better if T1 is used.

`longtable` is not actually related, you can delete the table with the same problem, but the hyperref bookmark file is very confused over `\'{e}` for some reason

```
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{Ap\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {e\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \
spacefactor }\accent 19 e\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \futurelet \@let@token ndice.alph1.Alph1}{Ap\351ndice Longtable examp
le}{}% 2
```

Note that you should not place `longtable` in a `center` environment.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work if `inputenc` is set to `utf8`. Do you understand why? (the whole matter revolves around `\spanishappendixname`).

Comment: Adding \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Note: I noted the known problem of bad quality fonts with T1 fontenc. To solve that I installed "cm-super" package and I had to add the "-Pcm-super" switch in "dvi2ps".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is very similar to [How to make appendix and hyperref packages work together with cyrillic (non ASCII) characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41649/how-to-make-appendix-and-hyperref-packages-work-together-with-cyrillic-non-asci)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\oriAlph\Alph
\let\orialph\alph
\renewcommand{\@resets@pp}{\par
  \@ppsavesec
  \stepcounter{@pps}
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \if@chapter@pp
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
    \renewcommand\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}%
  \else
    \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
    \renewcommand\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}%
  \fi
  \if@pphyper
    \if@chapter@pp
      \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\theH@pps.\oriAlph{chapter}}%
    \else
      \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\theH@pps.\oriAlph{section}}%
    \fi
    \def\Hy@chapapp{appendix}%
  \fi
  \restoreapp
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
   Chapter text
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Example}
x
\end{appendices}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

If you remove the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, the problem can be reproduced.

Of course, loading `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is recommended for Spanish.

Comment: this makes it work with `utf8` encoding too which `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` by itself does not.

Comment: @jfbu Yes, you are right.

Comment: The maintainers of `appendix` package should presumably incorporate this bug fix.