# Issues with longtable environment

Tags: tables, longtable

I have used this site with no problems to generate fast Latex code for small and medium size tables: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

This time I'm trying to build a very long table which needs more than one page. When I used the table/tabular environment, I didn't encounter issues, but the table was only one page, it did not continue next page, so it's useless. When I tried the longtable environment I get these errors:

```
! Argument of \@let@token has an extra }
! Paragraph ended before \@let@token was complete.
! Paragraph ended before \contentsline was complete
```

I think the site is redundant when defining the colors, but this is the whole code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{makeidx} % needed for creating an index
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border settings
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{longtable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
 \begin{document}
 \frontmatter
 \listoffigures
 \newpage
 \listoftables
 \newpage
 \tableofcontents
 \mainmatter
 \chapter{First chapter}
 \section{F1}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Table}
\begin{longtable}{|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}\\
\hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Cantidad}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Designante}}                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Referencia}}                                                                       & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Encapsulado}}                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{No. de parte}}                                                       \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} AC/DC Converter}                                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Power Module\\ 20W 85-264Vin 5Vout 4A\end{tabular}}             & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} RAC20-05SK}                                                                  \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 7}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}TP1, TP2, TP3, TP4, TP5\\ TP6, TP7\end{tabular}}                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} Test points}                                                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMD}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} 5019}                                                                        \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 7}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}AC1, AC2, AC3, AC4\\ AC5, M+, M-\end{tabular}}                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Metal Terminals PCB}                                                                       & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} 726386-2}                                                                    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} F1}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fusible Cerámica\\ 25A/250\end{tabular}}                        & {\color[HTML]{000000} 6.3x32mm}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0314025.MXP}                                                                 \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} F1 (Clips)}                                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} Clips para fusible}                                                                        & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} 01220083Z}                                                                   \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} MOV1}                                                                                        & {\color[HTML]{000000} Varistor 150V 2.5kA}                                                                       & {\color[HTML]{000000} Through Hole}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} B72210S0151K101}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R28}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Termistor \\ \$2R 25A\end{tabular}}                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} SL32 2R025}                                                                  \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} BR1}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Puente Rectificador\\ 35A\end{tabular}}                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} GBPC3506}                                                                    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C1}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Capacitor Aluminio\\ 250V $1500\mu F$\end{tabular}}             & {\color[HTML]{000000} Snap In}                                                & {\color[HTML]{000000} 380LX152M250A052}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C2}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC Capacitor630volts $0.1\mu F$ X7R}                                                     & {\color[HTML]{000000} 2225}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C2225C104KBRACTU}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R7}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 100k/1W}                                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} 2512}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} AC2512JK-07100KL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 4}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} LD1,  LD2, LD3, LD6}                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMD LED Red Diffused}                                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} EL-19-217/R6C-ALM2VY/3T}                                                     \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 7}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}R4, R6, R15, R9, R36, \\ R34, R18\end{tabular}}                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 10k 1/8W}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} AT0805BRD0710KL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 4}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R1, R2, R11, R35}                                                                            & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 174R 1/8W}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RC0805FR-07174RL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 10}                & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}R3, R14, R20, R21, R42\\ R38, R39, R16, R17, R33\end{tabular}}    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1k 1/8W}                                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RT0805CRE071KL}                                                              \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R5}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 39R 1/4W}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 1206}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RT1206BRD0739RL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 3}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} Q1, Q2, Q3}                                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} BJT NPN 0.6A 40V}                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} SOT-23-3}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} SST2222AHZGT116}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} LD5}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Green SMD LED}                                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} 19-21SYGC/S530-E2/TR8}                                                       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} VO1, VO2}                                                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} OPTOISOLATOR 4.17KV TRIAC}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 6-SMD}                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} MOC3061SM}                                                                   \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} TR1}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Triac 600V 35A}                                                                            & {\color[HTML]{000000} TO-220-2}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} Q6035RH5}                                                                    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C3, C4}                                                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} Capacitor de película0.01$\mu F$ 630V}                                                     & {\color[HTML]{000000} Radial}                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} BFC236969103}                                                                \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 4}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R8,  R10, R12, R13}                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 330R 1/8W}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RE0805FRE07330RL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} K1}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Relay 5VDC 1 Form C (SPDT-NO, NC)}                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} ALQ105}                                                                      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} D6}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Fast Rectifier Diode 2.0A}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}SMB\\ DO-214AA\end{tabular}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 512-ES2D}                                                                    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} TR2}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Triac 16 A 600 V}                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} D2PAK}                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} T1650-600G-TR}                                                               \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} LD4}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} LED SMD Blue Water Clear}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} EL-19-21/BHC-AN1P2/3T}                                                       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R24}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 680R 1/8W}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RC0805FR-07680RL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U7}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Gate Drivers}                                                                              & {\color[HTML]{000000} PG-DSO-8-51}                                            & {\color[HTML]{000000} 1EDI60N12AF}                                                                 \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U6}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Isolated DC/DC Converters \\ 1W 05Vin 12Vout 84mA\end{tabular}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMD}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} R1SE-0512/H2-R}                                                              \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U8}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Board Mount Current Sensors}                                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} PG-TISON-8-1}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} TLI4970D050T5XUMA1}                                                          \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} Q4}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} IGBT TRENCHSTOP  600V 80A}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} TO-247-3}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} IKW50N60DTPXKSA1}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} D5}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Rectifiers 50A, 600V Ultrafast Diode}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} TO-247-2}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} RURG5060-F085}                                                               \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 10}                & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C5, C7,  C9, C10, C13, \\ C15, C10, C16\\ C18, C19,\end{tabular}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC capacitor 16V 0.1$muF$ X7R}                                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C0603C104J4RAC}                                                              \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 3}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C6, C11, C12}                                                                                & {\color[HTML]{000000} Capacitor electrolítico 16V 100$\mu F$}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Radial Leaded}                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} ULD1C101MED1TD}                                                              \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C14}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC Capacitor 25V 1$muF$ X7R}                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C0805C105J3RACTU}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R29, R30}                                                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 10R 1/2W}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 1210}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RC1210JR-0710RL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R25}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1/8W 100k}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RC0805DR-07100KL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R26}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1/8W 47k}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RT0805BRD0747KL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R41}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1/8W 20k}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} AT0805BRD0720KL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} D11}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} TVS Diodes 600W 5.0V}                                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMB}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMBJ5.0A-TR}                                                                 \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} J1, J2}                                                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} CONN HEADER VERT 3POS 2.54MM}                                                              & {\color[HTML]{000000} Through Hole}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} SWR25X-NRTC-S03-ST-BA}                                                       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U2}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Op Amps Dual 2.7V}                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} SOIC-8}                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} MCP602-I/SN}                                                                 \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 3}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} JP1, JP2, JP5}                                                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} 2.54mm Hdr 3P Single Str Gold}                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} Straight Pin}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pin: 61300311121\\ Jumper: 382811-8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U1}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Analog Dual Comparators}                                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} SOIC-8}                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} LM393MX/NOPB}                                                                \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} J3}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} CONN HEADER VERT 4POS 2.54MM}                                                              & {\color[HTML]{000000} Through Hole}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} SWR25X-NRTC-S04-ST-BA}                                                       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R19, R22, R27}                                                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1/8W 100R}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} AT0805DRD07100RL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} Microcontrolador}                                                                            & {\color[HTML]{000000} Development Boards \& Kits - ARM STM32}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} NUCLEO-L432KC}                                                               \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U3}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} LVDS Interface IC Single Full-Duplex}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} SOIC-8 150mil}                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} SN65LVDS179DR}                                                               \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C8}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC Capacitor 10V 1000pF}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0402}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C0402C102J8RACTU}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U5}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Ethernet Connectors Female 8P Vertical}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Through Hole}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} 615008138021}                                                                \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C17}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC Capacitor 16V 1$muF$ X7R}                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C0603X105M4RACAUTO}                                                          \\ \hline
\end{longtable}   
\newpage
\chapter{Another appendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a compilable code, not just a snippet?

Comment: My code is way too long. I will update the question adding the packages I'm using. The problem only comes when I use this table.

Comment: I have already updated the question.

Comment: The error seems to be connected to the `spanish` etc. options of `babel`

Comment: (i) your table is unnecessary complicated, if you will remove all color declaration in table you will obtain the very same result (ii) your table is to wide that can be fit on page (iii) if instead of  `appendices` you will use switch `appendix` your document is possible to compile without errors.

Comment: But if I replace appendices with appendix, then I won't see the "Appendix" word in the ToC.

Comment: I know the table is too wide, but I can fit it in one page by resizing the whole box, or reducing the font size.

Comment: @XavierPachecoPaulino: You're loading some packages twice or in the wrong order. Also `xcolor` supersedes `color`, so keep `xcolor`

Comment: I'm checking your answer now. I will report back soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues here (apart from the table being to be too wide -- I do not address this 'feature', however)

First issue: `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` needs a special fontencoding, so `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is necessary.

Second issue: The `appendix` packages uses the babel form of the appendixname, i.e. `Apéndice`, which is taken by `hyperref` to create a hyperanchor, resulting in an anchor name with accents, which fails miserably.

The solution is to force another anchor name prefix for chapters within `appendices`, i.e. `\def\Hy@chap{appendixchapters}` (or something else not screwing up the linking system and other commands). This is done with the `\xapptocmd` setup before `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{makeidx} % needed for creating an index
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border settings
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\makeatletter

\xapptocmd{\appendices}{%
  \def\Hy@chapapp{appendixchapters}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


 \frontmatter
 \listoffigures
 \newpage
 \listoftables
 \newpage
 \tableofcontents
 \mainmatter
 \chapter{First chapter}
 \section{F1}

\begin{appendices}



\chapter{Table}
\begin{longtable}{|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}c |}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}\\
\hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Cantidad}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Designante}}                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Referencia}}                                                                       & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Encapsulado}}                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{No. de parte}}                                                       \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} AC/DC Converter}                                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Power Module\\ 20W 85-264Vin 5Vout 4A\end{tabular}}             & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} RAC20-05SK}                                                                  \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 7}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}TP1, TP2, TP3, TP4, TP5\\ TP6, TP7\end{tabular}}                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} Test points}                                                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMD}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} 5019}                                                                        \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 7}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}AC1, AC2, AC3, AC4\\ AC5, M+, M-\end{tabular}}                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Metal Terminals PCB}                                                                       & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} 726386-2}                                                                    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} F1}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fusible Cerámica\\ 25A/250\end{tabular}}                        & {\color[HTML]{000000} 6.3x32mm}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0314025.MXP}                                                                 \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} F1 (Clips)}                                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} Clips para fusible}                                                                        & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} 01220083Z}                                                                   \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} MOV1}                                                                                        & {\color[HTML]{000000} Varistor 150V 2.5kA}                                                                       & {\color[HTML]{000000} Through Hole}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} B72210S0151K101}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R28}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Termistor \\ \$2R 25A\end{tabular}}                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} SL32 2R025}                                                                  \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} BR1}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Puente Rectificador\\ 35A\end{tabular}}                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} GBPC3506}                                                                    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C1}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Capacitor Aluminio\\ 250V $1500\mu F$\end{tabular}}             & {\color[HTML]{000000} Snap In}                                                & {\color[HTML]{000000} 380LX152M250A052}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C2}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC Capacitor630volts $0.1\mu F$ X7R}                                                     & {\color[HTML]{000000} 2225}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C2225C104KBRACTU}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R7}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 100k/1W}                                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} 2512}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} AC2512JK-07100KL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 4}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} LD1,  LD2, LD3, LD6}                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMD LED Red Diffused}                                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} EL-19-217/R6C-ALM2VY/3T}                                                     \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 7}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}R4, R6, R15, R9, R36, \\ R34, R18\end{tabular}}                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 10k 1/8W}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} AT0805BRD0710KL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 4}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R1, R2, R11, R35}                                                                            & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 174R 1/8W}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RC0805FR-07174RL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 10}                & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}R3, R14, R20, R21, R42\\ R38, R39, R16, R17, R33\end{tabular}}    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1k 1/8W}                                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RT0805CRE071KL}                                                              \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R5}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 39R 1/4W}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 1206}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RT1206BRD0739RL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 3}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} Q1, Q2, Q3}                                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} BJT NPN 0.6A 40V}                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} SOT-23-3}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} SST2222AHZGT116}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} LD5}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Green SMD LED}                                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} 19-21SYGC/S530-E2/TR8}                                                       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} VO1, VO2}                                                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} OPTOISOLATOR 4.17KV TRIAC}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 6-SMD}                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} MOC3061SM}                                                                   \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} TR1}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Triac 600V 35A}                                                                            & {\color[HTML]{000000} TO-220-2}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} Q6035RH5}                                                                    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C3, C4}                                                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} Capacitor de película0.01$\mu F$ 630V}                                                     & {\color[HTML]{000000} Radial}                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} BFC236969103}                                                                \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 4}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R8,  R10, R12, R13}                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 330R 1/8W}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RE0805FRE07330RL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} K1}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Relay 5VDC 1 Form C (SPDT-NO, NC)}                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} ALQ105}                                                                      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} D6}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Fast Rectifier Diode 2.0A}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}SMB\\ DO-214AA\end{tabular}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 512-ES2D}                                                                    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} TR2}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Triac 16 A 600 V}                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} D2PAK}                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} T1650-600G-TR}                                                               \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} LD4}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} LED SMD Blue Water Clear}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} EL-19-21/BHC-AN1P2/3T}                                                       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R24}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 680R 1/8W}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RC0805FR-07680RL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U7}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Gate Drivers}                                                                              & {\color[HTML]{000000} PG-DSO-8-51}                                            & {\color[HTML]{000000} 1EDI60N12AF}                                                                 \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U6}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Isolated DC/DC Converters \\ 1W 05Vin 12Vout 84mA\end{tabular}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMD}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} R1SE-0512/H2-R}                                                              \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U8}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Board Mount Current Sensors}                                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} PG-TISON-8-1}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} TLI4970D050T5XUMA1}                                                          \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} Q4}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} IGBT TRENCHSTOP  600V 80A}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} TO-247-3}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} IKW50N60DTPXKSA1}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} D5}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Rectifiers 50A, 600V Ultrafast Diode}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} TO-247-2}                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} RURG5060-F085}                                                               \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 10}                & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C5, C7,  C9, C10, C13, \\ C15, C10, C16\\ C18, C19,\end{tabular}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC capacitor 16V 0.1$muF$ X7R}                                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C0603C104J4RAC}                                                              \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 3}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C6, C11, C12}                                                                                & {\color[HTML]{000000} Capacitor electrolítico 16V 100$\mu F$}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Radial Leaded}                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} ULD1C101MED1TD}                                                              \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C14}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC Capacitor 25V 1$muF$ X7R}                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C0805C105J3RACTU}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R29, R30}                                                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 10R 1/2W}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 1210}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RC1210JR-0710RL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R25}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1/8W 100k}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RC0805DR-07100KL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R26}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1/8W 47k}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} RT0805BRD0747KL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R41}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1/8W 20k}                                                                  & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} AT0805BRD0720KL}                                                             \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} D11}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} TVS Diodes 600W 5.0V}                                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMB}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} SMBJ5.0A-TR}                                                                 \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} J1, J2}                                                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} CONN HEADER VERT 3POS 2.54MM}                                                              & {\color[HTML]{000000} Through Hole}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} SWR25X-NRTC-S03-ST-BA}                                                       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U2}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Op Amps Dual 2.7V}                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} SOIC-8}                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} MCP602-I/SN}                                                                 \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 3}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} JP1, JP2, JP5}                                                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} 2.54mm Hdr 3P Single Str Gold}                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} Straight Pin}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pin: 61300311121\\ Jumper: 382811-8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U1}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Analog Dual Comparators}                                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} SOIC-8}                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} LM393MX/NOPB}                                                                \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} J3}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} CONN HEADER VERT 4POS 2.54MM}                                                              & {\color[HTML]{000000} Through Hole}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} SWR25X-NRTC-S04-ST-BA}                                                       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 2}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} R19, R22, R27}                                                                               & {\color[HTML]{000000} Resistencia SMD 1/8W 100R}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0805}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} AT0805DRD07100RL}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} Microcontrolador}                                                                            & {\color[HTML]{000000} Development Boards \& Kits - ARM STM32}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} -}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} NUCLEO-L432KC}                                                               \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U3}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} LVDS Interface IC Single Full-Duplex}                                                      & {\color[HTML]{000000} SOIC-8 150mil}                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} SN65LVDS179DR}                                                               \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C8}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC Capacitor 10V 1000pF}                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0402}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C0402C102J8RACTU}                                                            \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} U5}                                                                                          & {\color[HTML]{000000} Ethernet Connectors Female 8P Vertical}                                                    & {\color[HTML]{000000} Through Hole}                                           & {\color[HTML]{000000} 615008138021}                                                                \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} 1}                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} C17}                                                                                         & {\color[HTML]{000000} MLCC Capacitor 16V 1$muF$ X7R}                                                             & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0603}                                                   & {\color[HTML]{000000} C0603X105M4RACAUTO}                                                          \\ \hline
\end{longtable}   
\newpage
\chapter{Another appendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

See also

[Tex does not compile when jointly using longtable, appendix, hyperref, and babel (spanish). Error: "! Argument of \@let@token has an extra }"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222791/tex-does-not-compile-when-jointly-using-longtable-appendix-hyperref-and-babel)

and

[Appendix TOC link does not work when using Polyglossia (TeX Live 2015)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306133/appendix-toc-link-does-not-work-when-using-polyglossia-tex-live-2015/306153?r=SearchResults&s=29|16.3875#306153)

Comment: hyperref uses \def\Hy@chapapp, so it would be better to use \def in your redefinition too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Agreed. I can't remember why I used `\gdef` at all in my linked answer

Comment: It works now. Thank you. Now I just need to resize the table to make it fit in one page because it's too wide and looks cut.

Comment: @XavierPachecoPaulino: Fitting the table to your needs is the bigger issue, I think ;-) Happy TeXing

Answer (score 3):

Two major issues with your code are (a) an unbelievable amount of code clutter, likely caused by the apparent use of tablegenerator.com to create the `longtable` code, and (b) the fact that it's much wider than the text block.

The following adjustments may go a long way toward fixing both issues: (i) I applied `\small` (for a 10% linear reduction in font size), (ii) reduced the amount of intercolumn whitespace, and (iii) introduced many new line breaks within cells. I also (iv) removed all `\color`-related directives, since they do nothing at all, and (v) switched from center-alignment of all cell contents to left (and top) alignment. I also tried to give the table a more open look by (vi) getting rid of all vertical lines and (vi) replacing most horizontal lines with whitespace.

A separate comment: I strongly recommend you load the `siunitx` package and use its `\SI` macro to typeset scientific units and their associated numeric values. If you use `\SI` consistently, you'll be assured that all units and numbers are typeset in a way that meets current scientific standards. I would also argue that writing, say, `\SI{1500}{\micro\farad}` instead of `$1500\mu F$` makes the input a lot easier to read and, if necessary, debug.

The following screenshot shows just the first few lines of the full `longtable`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm,hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} *{5}{l} @{}}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Cantidad}  & \textbf{Designante} & \textbf{Referencia} & \textbf{Encapsulado} & 
\textbf{No.\ de parte}
\\ \midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\tablename~\ref{my-label}, cont'd}\\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\textbf{Cantidad}  & \textbf{Designante} & \textbf{Referencia} & \textbf{Encapsulado} & 
\textbf{No.\ de parte}
\\ \midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1 & AC/DC Converter & 
 \mytab{Power Module\\ \SI{20}{\watt}, \SIrange{85}{264}{\volt} in, \\ \SI{5}{\volt} out, \SI{4}{\ampere}} 
 & -- & RAC20-05SK 
 \\ \addlinespace
 7 & 
 \mytab{TP1, TP2, TP3, TP4,\\ TP5, TP6, TP7} 
 & Test points & SMD & 5019 
 \\ \addlinespace
 7 & 
 \mytab{AC1, AC2, AC3, AC4,\\ AC5, M+, M$-$} 
 & Metal Terminals PCB & -- & 726386-2 
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & F1 & 
 \mytab{Fusible Cerámica\\ \SI{25}{\ampere}/250} 
 & 6.3$\times$32mm & 0314025.MXP 
 \\ \addlinespace
 2 & F1 (Clips) & Clips para fusible & -- & 01220083Z
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & MOV1 & Varistor \SI{150}{\volt} \SI{2.5}{\kilo\ampere} 
 & Through Hole & B72210S0151K101
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & R28 & 
 \mytab{Termistor \\ \$2R \SI{25}{\ampere}} 
 & -- & SL32 2R025
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & BR1 & 
 \mytab{Puente Rectificador\\ \SI{35}{\ampere}} 
 & -- & GBPC3506
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & C1 & 
 \mytab{Capacitor Aluminio\\ \SI{250}{\volt} \SI{1500}{\micro\farad}} 
 & Snap In & 380LX152M250A052
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & C2 & \mytab{MLCC Capacitor\\ \SI{630}{\volt} \SI{0.1}{\micro\farad} X7R}                           
 & 2225 & C2225C104KBRACTU
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & R7 & \mytab{Resistencia SMD\\100k/\SI{1}{\watt}} 
 & 2512 & AC2512JK-07100KL
 \\ \addlinespace
 4 & 
 \mytab{LD1, LD2, LD3,\\ LD6} & SMD LED Red Diffused & 0603 
 & \mytab{EL-19-217/\\R6C-ALM2VY/3T}
 \\ \addlinespace
 7 & \mytab{R4, R6, R15, R9, \\R36, R34, R18}          
 & \mytab{Resistencia SMD\\10k \SI{1/8}{\watt}} 
 & 0805 & AT0805BRD0710KL
 \\ \addlinespace
 4 & R1, R2, R11, R35 & 
 \mytab{Resistencia SMD\\174R \SI{1/8}{\watt}} 
 & 0805 & RC0805FR-07174RL
 \\ \addlinespace
 10 & \mytab{R3, R14, R20, R21,\\
    R42, R38, R39, \\R16, R17, R33}
 & \mytab{Resistencia SMD\\1k \SI{1/8}{\watt} } 
 & 0805 & RT0805CRE071KL
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & R5 & \mytab{Resistencia SMD\\39R \SI{1/4}{\watt}} 
 & 1206 & RT1206BRD0739RL
 \\ \addlinespace
 3 & Q1, Q2, Q3 & BJT NPN \SI{0.6}{\ampere} \SI{40}{\volt} 
 & SOT-23-3 & SST2222AHZGT116 
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & LD5 & Green SMD LED & 0603 & \mytab{19-21SYGC/\\S530-E2/TR8}
 \\ \addlinespace

 2 & VO1, VO2 & \mytab{OPTOISOLATOR\\\SI{4.17}{\kilo\volt} TRIAC} 
 & 6-SMD & MOC3061SM
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & TR1 & Triac \SI{600}{\volt} \SI{35}{\ampere} 
 & TO-220-2 & Q6035RH5
 \\ \addlinespace
 2 & C3, C4 & 
 \mytab{Capacitor de película\\ \SI{0.01}{\micro\farad} \SI{630}{\volt}} 
 & Radial& BFC236969103
 \\ \addlinespace
 4 & R8, R10, R12, R13 & 
 \mytab{Resistencia SMD\\330R 1/8W}                                 
 & 0805 & RE0805FRE07330RL
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & K1 & \mytab{Relay \SI{5}{\volt} DC 1 Form C\\(SPDT-NO, NC)} 
 & -- & ALQ105
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & D6 & Fast Rectifier Diode \SI{2.0}{\ampere}                                    
 & \mytab{SMB\\ DO-214AA} & 512-ES2D
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & TR2 & Triac 16 A 600 V & D2PAK & T1650-600G-TR
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & LD4 & LED SMD Blue Water Clear & 0603 & 
 \mytab{EL-19-21/\\ BHC-AN1P2/3T}
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & R24 & Resistencia SMD 680R 1/8W & 0805 & RC0805FR-07680RL
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & U7 & Gate Drivers & PG-DSO-8-51 & 1EDI60N12AF
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & U6 & 
 \mytab{Isolated DC/DC Converters \\ 1W 05Vin 12Vout 84mA} 
 & SMD & R1SE-0512/H2-R
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & U8 & Board Mount Current Sensors & PG-TISON-8-1 & TLI4970D050T5XUMA1
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & Q4 & 
 \mytab{IGBT TRENCHSTOP\\ \SI{600}{\volt} \SI{80}{\ampere}} 
 & TO-247-3 & IKW50N60DTPXKSA1
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & D5 & 
 \mytab{Rectifiers \SI{50}{A} \SI{600}{\volt}\\ Ultrafast Diode} 
 & TO-247-2 & RURG5060-F085
 \\ \addlinespace
 10 & \mytab{C5, C7, C9, C10, \\C13, C15, C10, \\
 C16, C18, C19} & 
 \mytab{MLCC capacitor\\ \SI{16}{\volt} \SI{0.1}{\micro\farad} X7R} 
 & 0603 & C0603C104J4RAC
 \\ \addlinespace
 3 & C6, C11, C12 & 
 \mytab{Capacitor electrolítico\\ \SI{16}{\volt} \SI{100}{\micro\farad}} 
 & Radial Leaded & ULD1C101MED1TD
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & C14 & 
 \mytab{MLCC Capacitor\\ \SI{25}{\volt} \SI{1}{\micro\farad} X7R} 
 & 0805 & C0805C105J3RACTU
 \\ \addlinespace
 2 & R29, R30 & Resistencia SMD 10R 1/2W & 1210 & RC1210JR-0710RL
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & R25 & Resistencia SMD 1/8W 100k & 0805 & RC0805DR-07100KL
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & R26 & Resistencia SMD 1/8W 47k & 0805 & RT0805BRD0747KL 
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & R41 & Resistencia SMD 1/8W 20k & 0805 & AT0805BRD0720KL 
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & D11 & TVS Diodes 600W 5.0V & SMB & SMBJ5.0A-TR
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & J1, J2 & 
 \mytab{CONN HEADER VERT\\ 3POS \SI{2.54}{\milli\meter}} 
 & Through Hole & 
 \mytab{SWR25X-NRTC-\\ S03-ST-BA}
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & U2 & Op Amps Dual 2.7V & SOIC-8 & MCP602-I/SN 
 \\ \addlinespace
 3 & JP1, JP2, JP5 & 
 \mytab{2.54mm Hdr 3P Single\\ Str Gold} & Straight Pin 
 & \mytab{Pin: 61300311121\\ Jumper: 382811-8} \\ \addlinespace
 1 & U1 & Analog Dual Comparators & SOIC-8 & LM393MX/NOPB
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & J3 & 
 \mytab{CONN HEADER VERT\\ 4POS \SI{2.54}{\milli\meter}} 
 & Through Hole & 
 \mytab{SWR25X-NRTC-\\ S04-ST-BA}
 \\ \addlinespace
 2 & R19, R22, R27 & 
 \mytab{Resistencia SMD\\ 1/8W 100R} & 0805 & AT0805DRD07100RL
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & Microcontrolador & 
 \mytab{Development Boards \& \\Kits -- ARM STM32} & - & NUCLEO-L432KC
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & U3 & 
 \mytab{LVDS Interface IC\\ Single Full-Duplex} & SOIC-8 150mil & SN65LVDS179DR
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & C8 & 
 \mytab{MLCC Capacitor\\ \SI{10}{\volt} \SI{1000}{\pico\farad}} & 0402 & C0402C102J8RACTU 
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & U5 & 
 \mytab{Ethernet Connectors\\ Female 8P Vertical} & Through Hole & 615008138021 
 \\ \addlinespace
 1 & C17 & 
 \mytab{MLCC Capacitor\\ 
 \SI{16}{\volt} \SI{1}{\micro\farad} X7R} & 0603 & 
 \mytab{C0603X105M4-\\RACAUTO} \\ 
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```